# Server situated on two physical networks - Bad idea or not

Tags: network, corporate-policy

*The run down:*

1. Windows Server A (from here on referred to as 'the server') exists on the corporate network (ref as **Corporate**).
2. A separate physical network exists for the Telecommunications Department - we'll call it **Telecomms** Network.
3. A Telecommunication "Specialist" from another department is trying to convince managers to add in an additional network card in **the server**.  He then proposes that the second network card be provisioned on the **Telecomms** network so that the Telecomms users have access to the machine and its data.

I flat out said no and that they should look at implementing DMZ's and proper Jump Server / Firewall rules for this.

I need to back up my statement with a few guides and recommendations from published sources otherwise my manager and subsequent managers will just think I'm being difficult.  Its hard working with a bunch of Electrical Engineers.

*(TL;DR)*
My question is this, are there any resources / recommendations available to me that clearly outlines the above mentioned scenario?  One server, on two networks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The justification you should give is not a technical one. You should phrase it in terms of risk.

Put simply:

- The corporate network contains information that is sensitive.
- The systems connected to that network and the and users that use them have a certain level of risk associated with them.
- The security controls on the corporate network have been calculated to sufficiently mitigate that risk.
- Any change in risk means that the security controls need to be re-evaluated.
- Bridging the two networks incurs significant risk, due to the additional attack surface and potential for user behaviour to affect business-critical systems.
- Failing to account for additional risk will result in a deficit of security coverage, leading to a potential for heavy financial losses.

As you noted, jump boxes are ideal for this situation. They're much cheaper than trying to apply the same security requirements to both network when they're at completely different risk levels.

Comment: Question for you - If you had an ESX farm, would you allow a DMZ host to be VLANd on the same farm as non DMZ equipment?

Comment: @makerofthings7 It depends. I think VM separation in ESX is reasonable enough that I'd be reasonably happy putting two different sensitivity level systems on the same box. I don't know about putting them on the same VLAN though - it seems like a bad idea. If it were something that'd be storing regulated data (e.g. PCI DSS) or protectively marked data, I'd want it on a completely separate dedicated box, with appropriate dedicated controls in place.

Answer (score 6):

I think I would tackle it in this manner:

> Why is there an existing separation of the physical networks?

By installing another NIC in the server and connecting it to the other network you are in effect bridging the networks, physically and via NetBIOS. This renders the whole point of keeping the networks separate essentially moot.

> What is the sensitivity / classification of the data stored on the server?

This would help determine what level of protection needs to be deployed to protect the data on the server.

If you do lose this battle (the cost for an additional network card is MUCH cheaper than a proper firewall / DMZ architecture) there are still a few things you can do to help reduce the risk such as configuring IPsec to only allow the specific ports & protocols required for specific individuals to access the information.

I know you asked for specific quotes from published sources, but I think they may be a bit difficult since this a fundamental security philosophy of "keep things separate - access to information on a need to know basis" type scenario.

Comment: I'd add to this answer, "What services on **corporate** are needed by **telecomms** and for what business purpose?"  Unless a server is configured to be a bridge, *i.e.* to do packet forwarding, something you *do not* want to do, the proposed configuration would give access only to the server, and not to all of the **corporate* network.  Of course, it could easily "become mis-configured" later to act as a bridge.

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely on the right track refusing this, and there are two main points to why. The first one is more operational, the second is more risk related. Ultimately, however the important thing is to call these risks out and balance them with the cost/benefit involved. If your network already has a firewall and DMZ configured, then it should be easy enough to add the server to the DMZ and open up the necessary ports. If you don't then it could be a lot of work just for one system. Also, this setup is often called dual-homed or multi-homed, which may aid you in finding more documentation about it.

As mentioned in other responses, a dual-homed Windows system can sometimes cause issues. Programs may not expect this, and it seems that sometimes you can run into problems because of this. I'd like to say this is an old school problem, but I've seen it fairly recently so you can't discount it. Basically you're adding an edge case to your network, and there is rarely a real reason to do that.

Secondly is the risk you'd be accepting doing this. Obviously exposing this host on both networks potentially makes it easier for an attacker to jump between them. Using a network firewall (or load balancer) and DMZ model allows you to potentially reduce your attack surface. It sounds like the corporate network is more sensitive, so this system would be an obvious target for an attacker.

I don't have any specific best practices or documentation I can point to unfortunately, but I would recommend the same thing I would for any system. You should expose only strictly necessary ports on the telecomms side and ensuring this host has as little connectivity as possible to the rest of the corporate network. This way it increases the difficulty of pivoting around your network if the host is compromised. You should also consider host hardening as well. 
You can find information about dual-homed servers and security risks with some searching:
https://www.tofinosecurity.com/blog/dual-homed-machines-are-juiciest-targets
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Security/Misc/Q_21610476.html

Comment: Please reformat your answer. Right now it is one large wall of text, and is difficult to read. Paragraphs are your friend.

Comment: Thanks, still getting used to this site. I actually had paragraphs in my text but it didn't come across in the answer itself.

Comment: Using dualhomed systems as jumping points when attacking a network is often called pivoting. Metasploit for example contains extra modules to achieve this by Routing malicious traffic through target machines. Metasploit Pro even provides VPN features for pivoting that can be used to attack "deeper subnets". Maybe this also helps you finding security papers on this regard.

Answer (score 0):

If your Company is segmenting it's Networks based on a risk-zone model you could also verify if the two Networks have different risk-classifications.

Somewhere in your security policy it should say: you are not allowed to Bridge two seperate security zones by any other means than a Firewall that only allows necessary connections and is logging and enforcing those Connections according to the security policy.

From an operational standpoint you could argue that it introduces more complexity and thus potential sources of errors that will bite you in the ass when there is a performance or connectivity issue.